# Piping grep to cut

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This line:

```
echo $(grep Uid /proc/1/status) | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Produces output:

```
0
```

This line:

```
grep Uid /proc/1/status | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Produces output:

```
Uid:    0   0   0   0
```

My goal was the first output. My question is, why the second command does not produce the output I expected. Why am I required to echo it?

Comment: Perhaps there are TABS in the output

Comment: ahh yes, they are tabs and not spaces! thank you. I guess they get converted automatically when turned into a string

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Po 'Uid:\t\K[0-9]+' /proc/1/status`

Comment: See `grep Uid: /proc/1/status | cat -A`. `^I` represents a TAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to change the Output Field Separator or `OFS` variable in the bash shell

```
IFSOLD="$IFS" # IFS for Internal field separator
IFS=$'\t'
grep 'Uid' /proc/1/status | cut -f 2
0 # Your result
IFS="$IFSOLD"
```

or the easy way

```
grep 'Uid' /proc/1/status | cut -d $'\t' -f 2
```

---

<sup>**Note :** By the way `tab` is the default delim for cut as pointed out [[ here ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149411/piping-grep-to-cut/47149494?noredirect=1#comment81249509_47149833)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`

```
awk '/Uid/ { print $2; }' /proc/1/status
```

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never need to write something like `echo $(...)` - it's *almost* equivalent to calling `...` directly. Try `echo "$(...)"` (which you should always use) instead, and you'll see it behaves like `...`.

The reason is because when the `$()` command substitution is invoked without quotes the resulting string is split by Bash into separate arguments before being passed to `echo`, and `echo` outputs each argument separated by a single space, regardless of the whitespace generated by the command substitution (in your case tabs).

As sjsam suggested, if you want to `cut` tab-delimited output, just specify tabs as the delimiter instead of spaces:

```
cut -d $'\t' -f 2
```

Comment: TAB is cut's default delimiter.

Comment: @Cyrus heh true, but I think it's more helpful in this context to be explicit.  Even outside SO I'd probably still specify the `-d` parameter to aid future readers of the code (possibly myself!).

Answer (score 0):

grep Uid /proc/1/status |sed -r “s/\s+/ /g” | awk ‘{print $3}’

Output
0